# Android application brought to front when status bar notification is created

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

Basically I was following the following tutorial on how to create status bar notification:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/displaying-status-bar-notifications-android

(using the classes MainActivity.java alarmDetail.java DisplayNotification.java half way down the page)

The problem I have is that when the notification is created, the application is also brought to the front; what changes would I need to make in order to prevent this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it come to front when the notification is selected or created?

Comment: it comes to front when it is created.

Answer (score 0):

try this: call this method like showNotification("statusbar title",ID)

```
NotificationManager mNM;
void showNoitification(String text, int id) {
    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // CharSequence text = "Batch action in progress";
    Notification notification = new Notification(
            android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float, text,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.defaults = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE
            + Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    // Intent pendingintent = new Intent(this, BlankActivity.class);
    Intent pendingintent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            pendingintent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "your application", text, contentIntent);
    // notification.deleteIntent;
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNM.notify(id, notification);

}
```

Comment: you wont get your application in front if u click on the notification.

Comment: i want the application to get in from when the notification is clicked. but the current problem is that the Activity for setting the alarm is getting in front when the notification is created. (the notification works fine)

Comment: yea try this, app wont come in front even if its created, I have put the pending Intent null. check by making intent null...!!

Comment: I just tried using your code above, the Activity is still brought to front when the notification is created. what do you mean by making intent null?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. Your solution will make the application not to come in from when the notification is clicked. But my problem is that the application comes in front when the notification is created on the status bar.

Comment: how the notification occurs in your activity? is it created from service or activity?

Comment: you should create a service extending the IntentService and create a notification from there, as a service has no UI, then no activity will come in front.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service running the notification in a new thread.